# Store device token in AppDelegate, then use it in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, devicetoken

I am trying to get the device token in my AppDelegate, and then use it in a function in my ViewController later.

I successfully retrieve the device token like so in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSString *tokenAsString = [[[deviceToken description]
                                 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: token forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

Then I am trying to use it in a function in my ViewController, but it is printing as `null`:

```
-(void)addDeviceToken{
    NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
    NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken);
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the variable to show up here?

Comment: Why is your method called `-addDeviceToken` if you are _retrieving_ the device token? (_not_ storing it). Naming consistency might sound superfluous, but it all adds up and comes back to bite you when you revisit your code -say- three months from now. Clarity pays off.

Comment: If you nslog the token string value in the app delegate before saving does it look like a valid nsstring?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I am adding it to my server's database.

Comment: @DallasJohnson Nothing prints when I do that. It's as if I didn't put `NSLog`, even though I did. I guess that's my first problem to figure out why that's happening

Comment: What is the "token" string which you use in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method? Use "tokenAsString" for set "deviceToken" object.

Comment: If NSLog isn't printing anything, it means that method isn't being called..

Answer (score 1):

Replace **token** with **tokenAsString**.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
NSString *tokenAsString = [[[deviceToken description]
                             stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: tokenAsString forKey:@"deviceToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];}
```